# Error running Clementine

Tags: 11.10, clementine

Recently I installed Clementine 1.0 media player. When I run the program, simply it crashes. Here I describe the situation:

```
$clementine    
22:27:59.162 DEBUG NetworkProxyFactory:30           Detected system proxy URLs: ("", "", "", "") 
22:27:59.162 DEBUG CoverProviders:34                Registered cover provider "Amazon" 
22:28:00.822 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:00.822 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:00.910 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:00.910 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.366 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.366 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.367 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "jamendo.songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.608 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.608 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:01.609 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "jamendo.songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.015 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.015 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.015 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "jamendo.songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.577 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.577 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.578 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "spotify_search_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.578 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "jamendo.songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.579 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "playlist_items" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.914 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.915 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "magnatune_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.916 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "spotify_search_songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.916 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "jamendo.songs" for %allsongstables 
22:28:02.917 INFO  Database:578                     Updating "playlist_items" for %allsongstables 
22:28:03.501 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "di" 
22:28:03.501 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "DigitallyImported" 
22:28:03.635 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Icecast" 
22:28:03.700 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Jamendo" 
22:28:03.759 DEBUG unknown                          Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-96lpIZpvgm,guid=4fc59d3beb26bd425de407800000003f"  
22:28:03.760 DEBUG unknown                          Registered DEC:  true  
22:28:04.312 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "lastfm" 
22:28:04.312 DEBUG CoverProviders:34                Registered cover provider "last.fm" 
22:28:04.313 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Last.fm" 
22:28:04.313 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "grooveshark" 
22:28:04.314 INFO  PlaylistManager:417              Registered special playlist type "grooveshark-search" 
22:28:04.318 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Grooveshark" 
22:28:04.324 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "magnatune" 
22:28:04.331 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Magnatune" 
22:28:04.365 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "SavedRadio" 
22:28:04.370 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "sky" 
22:28:04.370 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "SKY.fm" 
22:28:04.371 INFO  Player:533                       Registered URL handler for "somafm" 
22:28:04.371 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "SomaFM" 
22:28:04.372 DEBUG SpotifyService:70                Spotify system blob path: "/usr/bin/clementine-spotifyblob" 
22:28:04.372 DEBUG SpotifyService:71                Spotify local blob path: "/home/brallan/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version11-32bit/blob" 
22:28:04.372 INFO  PlaylistManager:417              Registered special playlist type "spotify-search" 
22:28:04.372 DEBUG InternetModel:94                 Adding internet service: "Spotify" 
22:28:04.473 WARN  IconLoader:54                    Couldn't load icon "clementine-panel" 
22:28:04.507 WARN  IconLoader:54                    Couldn't load icon "clementine-panel-grey" 
22:28:04.752 DEBUG GnomeGlobalShortcutBackend:50    registering 
22:28:04.960 DEBUG MainWindow:209                   Starting 
22:28:05.530 DEBUG MainWindow:267                   Initialising player 
22:28:05.611 DEBUG MainWindow:273                   Creating models 
22:28:05.632 DEBUG MainWindow:296                   Creating UI 
22:28:05.735 DEBUG MainWindow:663                   Creating equalizer 
22:28:05.735 DEBUG MainWindow:678                   Creating now playing widget 
22:28:05.983 DEBUG MainWindow:715                   Loading settings 
22:28:06.152 DEBUG MainWindow:761                   Initialising library 
22:28:06.154 DEBUG MainWindow:774                   Started 
22:28:06.170 WARN  unknown                          Invalid parent:  0xb6a2cab0 QtSingleApplication(0xbfae6b08, name = "clementine")  
22:28:06.174 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.176 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.182 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.183 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.187 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.190 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.203 WARN  unknown                          QAccessibleWidget::rect: This implementation does not support subelements! (ID 1 unknown for LineTextEdit) 
22:28:06.203 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.204 WARN  unknown                          QAccessibleWidget::rect: This implementation does not support subelements! (ID 2 unknown for LineTextEdit) 
22:28:06.204 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.205 WARN  unknown                          QAccessibleWidget::rect: This implementation does not support subelements! (ID 3 unknown for LineTextEdit) 
22:28:06.205 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.207 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.360 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.361 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.371 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.373 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.375 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.434 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.435 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.437 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.548 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.551 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.811 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.824 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.835 WARN  unknown                          Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself.  
22:28:06.862 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.865 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.870 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.873 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.875 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.877 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.891 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.892 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.892 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.892 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.892 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.892 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.895 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.896 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.898 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.900 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.902 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.903 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.905 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.907 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.907 WARN  unknown                          Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!  
22:28:06.907 ERROR unknown                          ASSERT: "interface->valueInterface()" in file accessible.cpp, line 280 
Aborted
```

If somebody would help me please. Thanks!

Comment: You should report a bug on the Clementine bug tracker. (PS I love the avatar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi
```